# Python - Flask Validate SelectField

Tags: python, validation, google-app-engine, flask, flask-wtforms

i'm novel in the python world  and i'm trying to use the external APIs with google apple engine, i would like make a form validate with a selectField filled with a json response of Api.

This is my code

```
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Nome', [required()])
    nazionalita = SelectField('Nazionalita',[required()])
    eta = IntegerField('Eta', [required()])
    Comment = TextAreaField('Commento', [required()])
    Data = DateTimeField('Data',[required()],format='%d/%m/%Y', )
    submit = SubmitField('Inserisci', [required()])

    def validate_nazionalita(form):
       if  not form.nazionalita.data == None:
          raise ValidationError('Nazionalita non selezionata')

@app.route('/insert', methods=['GET'])
def insert():
    form = CommentForm()
    url = 'https://ajayakv-rest-countries-v1.p.mashape.com/rest/v1/all'
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('X-Mashape-Key', MASHAPE_KEY)
    req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
    urlresponse = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = urlresponse.read()

    responde = make_response(content)

    responde.headers['content-type']='application/json'
    data = json.loads(responde.data)
    nation = list(data)
    scelte =[]
    scelte =  ([( s['callingCodes'] , s['name'] )for s in nation])
    form.nazionalita.choices= scelte
    return  render_template('insert.html', form=form)


@app.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    form = CommentForm(request.form)
    if not form.validation():
        return render_template('insert.html', form=form), 400
    return redirect('/')
```

and this is html page :

```
<form method="post" action="/insert">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      <div> {{form.name.label}}: {{form.name}}  </div>

        {% if form.name.errors %}
            <ul class=errors>
                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}


      <div> {{form.nazionalita.label}}: {{form.nazionalita}} </div>

        {% if form.nazionalita.errors %}
            <ul class=errors>
                {% for error in form.nazionalita.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

      <div> {{form.eta.label}}: {{form.eta}} </div>

        {% if form.eta.errors %}
            <ul class=errors>
                {% for error in form.eta.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

      <div> {{form.Data.label}}: {{form.Data}} </div>

        {% if form.Data.errors %}
            <ul class=errors>
                {% for error in form.Data.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

      <div> {{form.Comment.label}}: {{form.Comment}} </div>

        {% if form.Comment.errors %}
            <ul class=errors>
                {% for error in form.Comment.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

      <div> {{form.submit}} </div>
    </form>
```

if i remove the selectField all work well , but with it the error is :

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
     result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
     response = self.handle_exception(e)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/app/handlers/insert.py",  line 46, in submit
     if not form.validate():
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
     return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
     if not field.validate(self, extra):
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 193, in validate
     self.pre_validate(form)
     File "/home/roberto/Scrivania/simulazione/lib/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 468, in pre_validate
     for v, _ in self.choices:
     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
```

and i dont understand why e how resolved this.
thank you all.

Comment: Hello Roberto, welcome at Stackoverflow. To make sure you get fast and helpful responses have a look at the guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to narrow your code to describe your problem without much overhead.

Comment: Thank you mrleeh, I will take your advice

Comment: can you print your `scelte`?

Comment: @Tiny.D yes i can. The 'GET' method works and the selectField shows me the correct values.

Comment: ok, then can you share your full trace log of the error?

Comment: @Tiny.D  ok done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to reproduce your error: You are creating the choices in your view function for the GET method. But you are not adding them to the view function for your POST method. Fix this by modifying your `submit()` function slightly:

```
@app.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    form = CommentForm(request.form)
    scelte = [( s['callingCodes'] , s['name'] )for s in nation]
    form.nazionalita.choices= scelte

    if not form.validate():
        return render_template('insert.html', form=form), 400
    return redirect('/')
```

This way you add the choices also in your post function and you can validate them. An even cleaner approach would be to place the GET and the POST handler in the same function:

**NOTE:** In your original version the `form.validate()` function tries to find out if you made a valid choice by iterating through the `form.nazionalita.choices` list. As you didn't set any choices in your Form class it is `None`. And trying to iterate over `None` raises the Exception you have got.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Mrleeh  you mean , sholud  i nation as global var ? by the way my form seems dont have validation()  " AttributeError: 'CommentForm' object has no attribute 'validation'"

Comment: Have a look at http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#validating-forms. Try to modify your code to match this pattern and you should be good.